# Where to read about the Gathering Storms events?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Status quo has been the norm for the narrative of WarHammer 40k. However, through the [Gathering Storm](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Gathering_Storm) campain, Games Workshop decided to completely change the shape of the Galaxy: Cadia and Bieltan have fallen, a new Warp rift opened and a Primarch is back!

**Where can I read about these events?**

Are these novels related to the Gathering Storm and their aftermaths? So far, what I could gather:

1. The campaign supplements books: [Fall of Cadia](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Gathering_Storm:_Fall_of_Cadia), [Fracture of Bieltan](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Gathering_Storm:_Fracture_of_Biel-Tan) and [Rise of the Primarch](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Gathering_Storm:_Rise_of_the_Primarch).
2. The novel series [Dark Millenium](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Dark_Imperium_(Novel_Series))

Anything else?

Answer (score 5):

**[Watchers of the Throne: The Emperor's Legion](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Watchers_of_the_Throne:_The_Emperor%27s_Legion_(Novel))**

This book features a Custodian, Sister of Silence and the Chamberlain of the Highlords.
The book is set during the events of the gathering storm, and is mainly set on Holy Terra.

> The book itself features the second battle of terra, Guilliman returning to terra for the first time after his ressurection.

**[The Devastation of Baal](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/The_Devastation_of_Baal_(Novel))** 
This is mostly about the Blood angels and Dante

> Some cool stuff with Guilliman in the end, Dante is appointed as commander of Imperium Nihilus

**Ghost Warrior: Rise of the Ynnari**
Is about the aftermath for the Ynnari

Answer (score 5):

**TLDR**

- This depends on who you want to learn about.
- Gathering Storm (and the supplements you mention) are the starting point.
- The novel series you mention is the new line of books covering the new events.
- This is all relatively new so material is still being released.

So you are correct with the Gathering Storm release and Dark Imperium series as the new material. Gathering Storm is where everything started to kick off and was basically the build up to the "New Imperium" as it is now and the new events moving forward.

As far as the material for you to get your hands on to supplement what you have read from Gathering Storm it depends on what you want to learn. I do not know all of the related content that has been released, but, for example, I have read each of the mini series titles from the Legacy of Russ bundle that cover the events of *Curse of the Wulfen* and *Wrath of Magnus* more intimately.

From the Gathering Storm supplements we know that the Space Wolves ran around the galaxy collecting the Wulfen and then ran home to protect the Fenrisian system after the Thousand Sons invaded. The mini series goes into more detail of what planets were attacked, how and by whom (the Death Guard were there too), the rituals performed on them, how the Space Wolves fought back, etc. It appears that on Black Library the line was combined with a couple others and is available [here](https://www.blacklibrary.com/warhammer-40000/bundles/warzone-fenris-bundle.html) or each of the lines can be purchased separately...

As Nino has mentioned there are other titles that cover events that occurred in other parts and factions of the galaxy. My recommendation is to travel to the Black Library website or maybe to [Lexicanum](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Imperium_Nihilus) to search for factions or events you are interested in and scroll down to see their sources. Again, for example, the new Role Playing Game [*Wrath & Glory*](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Wrath_%26_Glory_Core_Rulebook) is set during the events of the Dark Imperium and there may be details of interest to you within that release...